# How can I verity two static methods invocations using PowerMock?

Tags: java, powermock

I have a simple class

```
public class A {
    public static int calc(){
        return anotherCalc();

    }

    public static int anotherCalc() {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

I need to verify is method `calc` fire an `anotherCalc` method? How can I do it with PowerMockito?

UPD:

I have a code which (I think) do the right verification. But I'm not sure.

```
    @Test
    public void should_invoke_anotherCalc_method() throws Exception {
        mockStatic(A.class);
        when(A.calc()).thenCallRealMethod();
        A.calc();
        verifyStatic(times(1));
        A.anotherCalc();
    }
```

Maybe anyone can say is it ok or not?

Comment: You've already asked this question. If you need to add details, edit it.

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating things. I think you should check that answer is 10 and ignore implementation details about calling another static function. This will simplify your test and give more freedom in  you future design changes

Comment: My real example is much complicated. It returns an a complex object.

Comment: So I need to now is my approach good or bad?

Comment: looks to me that you're doing it backwards.. that test looks like it would verify correctly if A.AnotherCalc() called A.calc()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way to verify that your test is doing what you expect is to simply change your CUT (code under test) to make the test fail.  For instance, temporarily comment out the call to "anotherCalc()" in the "calc()" method and run the test.  If it fails with an appropriate message, then you know that your test is doing what you expect.  Remove the comment markers and rerun the test, and it passes.

I'm not sure why you're calling "A.anotherCalc()" at the end of the test method.  That doesn't make sense.